# rails devise reset password token is replaced with user's email only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I use rails 3 and devise 3.0.3. My devise views and controllers are mostly default. Here is PasswordsController:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  layout "application_new"

  def new
    flash.clear
    super
  end

  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      respond_with({}, location: after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      flash[:notice] = t("errors.no_user")
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end

  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)

    if resource.errors.empty?
      resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, location: after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
    else
      flash[:notice] = resource.errors.full_messages
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end
end
```

And here is edit password form:

```
= form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put } do |f|
  h2 = t('signup.password_recovery')
  = f.hidden_field :reset_password_token
  .form-group
    = f.label :password, t("forms.new_password_label")
    = f.password_field :password, required: true, class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    = f.label :password_confirmation, t("forms.password_confirmation_label")
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation, required: true, class: "form-control"
  = f.submit t('users.account.save'), class: 'btn btn-fill orange'
```

Here's the mailer template:

```
= raw edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @resource.reset_password_token)
```

When I try to reset user's password, it works perfectly well in development. Which means, I get a letter with reset link, which contains reset password token in parameters and leads to edit password page with appropriate form and hidden field with aforementioned token in it.

In production, I get similar letter containing a reset link with reset password token in parameters (it is always right token I double checked it); however, when I open edit password page, I see user's email in hidden reset password token field instead of the token itself. I don't understand how it gets there. Any suggestions?

P.S. I've already seen this topic  [Rails 4 + Devise: Password Reset is always giving a "Token is invalid" error on the production server, but works fine locally.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018657/rails-4-devise-password-reset-is-always-giving-a-token-is-invalid-error-on) it isn't the case, because I get right token in parameters, the problem is that somehow I get user's email instead of the token in my form.

That's what I expect to see and what I get in development:
`<input id="user_reset_password_token" name="user[reset_password_token]" type="hidden" value="KyFVbsSUyAzsntDg4Dwf">`

That's what I get in production:
`<input id="user_reset_password_token" name="user[reset_password_token]" type="hidden" value="my_email@gmail.com">`

Comment: ` I see user's email in hidden reset password token field instead of the token itself` what do you mean by this, can you show an example of whats happening ?

Comment: I changed my question and added the examples.

Comment: can you also share the mailer template?

Comment: Sure. I added it right after the form.

Comment: I think you should be passing `@token` like this: `reset_password_token: @token` instead of `@resource.reset_password_token` .

Comment: No, It won't work, I wrote about it in my PS. It will work only for device 3.1.0, because of these changes https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/143794d701bcd7b8c900c5bb8a216026c3c68afc. In my case it does nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163545/discussion-between-enjaku-and-abhinay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root of the problem, it didn't have anything to do with Rails actually. Safari just autofilled that hidden input with my email. I solved that thanks to this discussion [Safari autofills hidden "reset password token" input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410160/safari-autofills-hidden-reset-password-token-input).